# Error while attempting to run Heroku app

Tags: ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've been trying to deploy my first Heroku app, but continue to run into problem after problem. I'll just go ahead and paste the error codes I'm getting hit with.

On heroku.open:

> Opening secure-reef-1182... failed
>   !    Heroku client internal error.
>   !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
>   !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
>
> Error:       undefined method `licenses=' for #<Gem::Specification name=multi_json >version=1.5.0> (NoMethodError)
>      Backtrace:   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:74:in`eval'
>                    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:388:in
>
> Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.33.5 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3

On heroku.ps

> === web: `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`
>   web.1: crashed 2013/01/02 21:07:51 (~ 4m ago)

And in my heroku.logs I get these type of error messages

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=secure-reef-1182.herokuapp.com >fwd=50.134.210.222 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Do you have anything else in the logs?  H10 indicates your app crashed - does your app throw any other exceptions?  Does it run locally?

Answer (score 0):

> "A crashed web process or a boot timeout on the web process will present this error."

- Make sure you are testing everything in a development environment
  first.
- If your app is running locally, check for global configurations needed to be set in heroku.